# How to extract fields of IObservable in Current in C#

Tags: c#, sql, system.reactive, streaminsight

Consider me new to the world of C# and the lingo associated with IObservable lingo.
I have a question on how to extract the info from Current. Here is my c# code:

```
    private static IObservable<T> ToObservableInterval<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, 
        TimeSpan period, System.Reactive.Concurrency.IScheduler scheduler)

        {
            return Observable.Using(
                () => source.GetEnumerator(),
                it => Observable.Generate(
                    default(object),
                    _ => it.MoveNext(),
                    _ => _,
                    _ =>
                  {
                        Console.WriteLine("Input {0}", it.Current);
                        return it.Current;
                  },
                    _ => period, scheduler));
    }
```

If I pass the values of this class in the source:

```
class LogEvent
    {
        public DateTime X { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ServerName { get; set; }
        public string Level { get; set; }

       public override string ToString()
       {
           return new { x, Id, ServerName, Level}.ToString();
       }
}
```

Is there a easy way to extract values of either x, Id, Level out of the Current representation?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what problem you are trying to solve?  It seems like you just want to observe the values in the enumerable stream with a small delay between each value, which you can do with: `enumerableSequence.ToObservable().Delay(period, scheduler)`

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just want to do something like this?

```
var query =
    from le in ToObservableInterval(items, timeSpan, scheduler)
    select le.ServerName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Enigmativity has answered the question however, I think it should be pointed out that you probably dont have to put so much effort in, when you could just use `Observable.Interval` and the `Zip` operator to this work.

Here is a [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) script that you can use to see that it will only pull values from the `IEnumerable<T>` as each period of time passes.

```
void Main()
{
    //GetNumbers().Dump();
    var period = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    var scheduler = Scheduler.Default;
    var source = GetNumbers();
    Observable.Interval(period, scheduler)
            .Zip(source, (a,b)=>b)
            .Dump();

}

// Define other methods and classes here

public IEnumerable<int> GetNumbers()
{
    var i = 0;
    while (i<10)
    {
        DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString("o").Dump();
        yield return i++;
    }
}
```

So you can reduce your `ToObservableInterval` method to just:

```
private static IObservable<T> ToObservableInterval<T>(
            IEnumerable<T> source, 
            TimeSpan period, 
            System.Reactive.Concurrency.IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return Observable.Interval(period, scheduler)
                         .Zip(source, (a,b)=>b);
    }
```

and then consume as per the answer above.

As the method is so small, you may even question if you need it at all?